# How do I avoid access denied (just checking a filename)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So I have a pretty basic problem here... we have an application which relies on a an xml file storing settings. once in a while this file is corrupted and the app will fail on startup. I want to write an app that will go find the USED file and the BACKUP file. The file the app uses is not always stored in the same location for various reasons (10 years of changes etc.), but it is always named the same.

SO the idea is I write this simple app which can go find all cases of the file on the system (generally either one or two HDD) it will be obvious which is used and which is backup.

Simple... but while iterating through using this code

```
Private Sub Command1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Command1.Click
    'variable to hold each hdd name eg: c:\
    Dim hdd As String




    Try

        For Each drive As IO.DriveInfo In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
            'asign the variable hdd a name for this run through
            hdd = drive.Name

            'search the hdd for the file user.config

            For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(hdd, "user.config", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

                'variable to hold the path for each found file
                Dim file As String = IO.Path.GetFullPath(filename)


                'add each found file to the list
                List1.Items.Add(file)

            Next


        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    'iterate through each found drive





End Sub
```

The problem I get is access denied...
[image]

So I think I should be able to just check permissions before I do anything with it? But then I am thinking I did not actually try to do anything but read it right? Or am I missing something...

I have tried changing permissions, running VS2010 as administrator etc. none of this worked.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

RtBackup is a system folder, and if you look at the permissions, only System (and not even admin) has access to it.  I suppose you could run your program as System, but that sounds like a dumb idea.  I would just catch the exception, maybe log it somewhere or show a console message and move along.

Comment: OK this is where I guess I'm stupid. I thought the try catch would do that, but it exits. I'll have to do some looking at what I missed there... feeling like I'm going to feel stupid in about 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You said: "I have tried changing permissions, running VS2010 as administrator etc. none of this worked."

When you say, "tried changing permission", what do you mean?  On what did you try to change permissions?  Running VS as admin won't do any good, as you found out.

The issue is the permissions on the folder RtBackup.  One option (maybe not the best?) is to go to

```
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI
```

Right click on the RtBackup folder and select Properties, go to the Security tab, Edit, Add, type "Everyone" in the bottom box, click Ok.  In the window 'Permissions for Rtbackup, make sure you have Everyone highlighted, and then give it Full Control. Ok.  Ok.

Keep in mind that in doing this, you have opened this folder wide up for full access to everyone and everything.  This may suffice for testing.  When you want to publish, what you'll want to do find out (or specify) which user your apps runs as, and give that user Read rights.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use the try-catch to skip cases where you don't have permission, then format your code as follows:

```
    For Each drive As IO.DriveInfo In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives

        'asign the variable hdd a name for this run through
        hdd = drive.Name

        Try

            'search the hdd for the file user.config
            For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(hdd, "user.config", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            'variable to hold the path for each found file
                Dim file As String = IO.Path.GetFullPath(filename)

                'add each found file to the list
                List1.Items.Add(file)

            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
           ' handle error here, or just do nothing
        End Try

    Next
```

Comment: "tried changing permission" I meant tried changing the app permissions.

I think this is actually a really stupid miss on my part. I have never dealt much with catching errors... very simple apps which this is not a problem. I have the try catch, I assumed this would catch an error and then return to processing code but it does not. Never occurred to me that the proper behavior here is look for the files and in every case I do not have permission just skip it. That's what I THOUGHT would happenb with try/catch when that did not happen I just kept plodding forward... I am working on that

Comment: Well, you are right that the try-catch can be used to skip cases where you don't have permisison.  But you just need to format things a little differently.  I don't think code works in comments, so I'll edit my answer above with how you can make this work.

Comment: I appreciate the help... but I think I am seeing the same problem after editing as you pointed out. I get an error on the first file/directory it tries to look at, and exits that for/next.  

I did make the edit as you recommended

Comment: I don't really understand what's going wrong...

The for/next throws an error on the first run through and is just exiting. I'm missing something simple here...